# Cross validated PCA in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, pca, cross-validation

I am analysing a chemometric dataset of roughly 300 variables and 24 samples. I want to use PCA for variable selection. Previously, I have used the prcomp function and selected the components which account for >95% of the variance, however I am aware that by doing this there is a danger of overfitting and modelling noise. Therefore, I would like to be able to cross validate my PCA model and plot the RMSECV of test and train models to aid in variable selection, as described in:
https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2014/ay/c3ay41907j

My dataset is too complex to upload, however here is a reproducible example of what I have done so far, using the wine dataset and a response to a previous question as an example:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/how-to-use-r-prcomp-results-for-prediction

```
library("rattle.data")
data("wine")

# all data model

model <- prcomp(wine[2:14], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

summary(model)

biplot(model)

# cross validation
# split data into 2 parts for pca training (75%) and prediction (25%)
set.seed(1)
samp <- sample(nrow(wine), nrow(wine)*0.75)
train <- wine[samp,]
valid <- wine[-samp,]



# conduct PCA on training dataset
model <- prcomp(train[,2:14], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
summary(model)

# prediction of PCs for validation dataset
pred <- predict(model, newdata=valid[,2:14])


###Plot result
COLOR <- c(2:4)
PCH <- c(1,16)

pc <- c(1,2) # principal components to plot


plot(model$x[,pc], col=COLOR[train$Type], cex=PCH[1], 
     xlab=paste0("PC ", pc[1], " (", expl.var[pc[1]], "%)"), 
     ylab=paste0("PC ", pc[2], " (", expl.var[pc[2]], "%)")
)
points(pred[,pc], col=COLOR[valid$Type], pch=PCH[2])
legend("topright", legend=levels(wine$Type), fill = COLOR, border=COLOR)
legend("topleft", legend=c("training data", "validation data"), col=1, pch=PCH)
```

My main questions are, have I gone about cross validating the model correctly, and how can I evaluate the cross validation error of fit (i.e. RMSECV) from the two models?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have a specific question about the programming *per se*, but only about the correctness of the approach. For this reason, I think this is a better fit for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).